# Generate own (stronger) RSA host key for OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I would like to replace the default 2048 bit host key generated when installing OpenSSH or starting it the first time with one of 4096 bit length.

This leads to two questions:

- Does OpenSSH allow running with a 4096 bit RSA host key (for SSH2 obviously)?
- How can `ssh-keygen` be convinced not to prompt for a passphrase?

The version of OpenSSH I am running is 6.6p1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever key-length is supported in `ssh-keygen` most likely would work with `sshd` as well.  Besides that, you should generate your host-keys with `ssh-keygen -h` anyways, so if `ssh-keygen` isn't totally dumb, it should inform you if the desired key-length is not supported for host keys.

The passphrase could be specified with `-N`; if you don't want the key to be encrypted, just specify an empty one (thus just hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> if it prompts you would have the same effect).